# Find the turning points for $|x-2| + \frac{a}{x}$

Tags: functions

I am working through a maths text book - as a hobby. I have been struggling with this.

The function *f* is defined by $f:x \rightarrow |x-2| + \frac{a}{x}$ where $x \in \Bbb R, x\ne0, a \in \Bbb R, a\ne\pm4$ or $0$. Determine the number of turning points of f for the different sets of values of a.

I have got so far:

When $x>2, y = x-2 + \frac{a}{x}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - \frac{a}{x^2} = 0$ when $x = \sqrt a$

When $x\lt2, y = 2-x + \frac{a}{x}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = -1 - \frac{a}{x^2} = 0$ when $x^2 = - a,$ so that $x= \sqrt a$ when $a<0$ - I am somewhat unsure about this last step.

I cannot find a neat, clear, methodical way to arrive at the answers in the book.

The book answer is $a\gt4:$ one;  $0\lt a\lt4$: none;  $-4\lt a\lt0$: tw0; $a\lt-4:$ one;

Comment: You have correctly found that e.g. when $x > 2$, $x=\sqrt{a}$ is a stationary point. So, putting these facts together, it is a stationary point if $\sqrt{a} > 2$, i.e. $a > 4$. Similarly for the other cases.

Comment: I have a mental block when $x<2, \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$ when $-1 = \frac{a}{x^2} \rightarrow -x^2 = a\rightarrow x= \sqrt -a$. I'm obviously making a basic mistake here but can't see it. In other words, I'm stuck when $x\lt2$

Comment: In such cases we need $a < 0$ in order for $x = \pm\sqrt{-a}$ to exist (as $a = 0$ is already excluded by the problem statement), and we also need either $\sqrt{-a} < 2$, i.e. $0 < -a < 4$, and thus $-4 < a < 0$, or $-\sqrt{-a} < 2$, which will be true for all values of $a<0$. Thus, for $-4<a<0$ you get $2$ stationary points (both $x=\sqrt{-a}$ and $x=-\sqrt{-a}$), whereas for $a<-4$ you only get the $1$ point at $x=-\sqrt{-a}$.

Comment: @PrasiortleThanks for the clarification.  Most helpful.